# ReactJS cannot have object properties displayed using map()

Tags: reactjs, reactjs.net

This my code in my component. What I ultimately want to do it build a select with the options being the list of friends returned from

```js
/*** @jsx React.DOM */

var FriendSelect = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
  return {
   friends: []
  };
 },
 componentDidMount: function(){
  this.loadFriends();
 },
 loadFriends: function (){
  
  $.ajax({
         async: true,
         type: "GET",
         url: "../../Messaging/_GetFriends",
         success: function (data) {
          this.setState({ friends: data });
          console.log("data in ajax: ",data);
         }.bind(this)
     });
     
 },
 handleSelections: function  (){
  console.log('selection changed');
 },
 render: function(){

     console.log('this.state.friends', this.state.friends);

  return (
   <div>
    {this.state.friends.map(function(friend){
     <span>{friend.text}</span>
    })}
   </div>
  );
 }
});

React.render(<FriendSelect />, document.getElementById('friendSelection'));
```

This is the json returned after the ajax call.

```js
[{"id":"8qdzmV","text":"fernando roman","firstName":"first","lastName":"last","pictureName":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","pictureExt":".jpg"},{"id":"8qdzmV","text":"Anthony Macias","firstName":"first2","lastName":"last2","pictureName":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","pictureExt":".jpg"},{"id":"8qdzmV","text":"Carla Velasco ","firstName":"first3","lastName":"last3","pictureName":"011ab238-0b3a-44ff-aeda-02e6fbdcca56","pictureExt":".jpg"}]
```

When the component gets rendered I don't get any errors, the issue is that the text property for each friend does not get rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `return` inside the `map`:

```
        <div>
            {this.state.friends.map(function(friend){
                return <span>{friend.text}</span>
            })}
        </div>
```

JSX doesn't have a side-effect of outputing - it just evaluates to an element that can then be returned.

You can avoid this if you enable es6 transpilation:

```
<div>{
    this.state.friends.map(friend => <span>{friend.text}</span>)
}</div>
```

You can do this by using browserify/reactify and amending your package.json:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "reactify",
        {
          "es6": true
        }
      ],
      "envify"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Daniel, thank you. All I did was add friend => and get rid of the function() code and it now works.

Comment: It may be that es6 is already being transpiled in your setup, or maybe you are using Firefox which has => function support - try in Chrome and IE to see if it still works

Comment: I'm using asp.net Mvc with ReactJS.net, that might be doing the trick. I tested it on chrome and it still working.